# State Management in React at component level

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

In case you are using Redux to manage the global state, how do you manage exclusive component state that used only by this component and its children(act like container)?

**Edit**
I am already using **useState()**.
I am asking for a better approach because I ended up with a lot of useState statements.

Any Ideas?

Comment: what do you mean by a complicated state?

Comment: More than one state that you need to pass them down to different children.

Comment: i use  MapStateToProps to change state.

Comment: I think you didn't get my question.
**MapStateToProps**: used to select a part from the store state and map it to props for your component.

My question here for a component state that is not part of the store yet, and I don't like to put it inside the store because it's used in the component and its children only.

Comment: `How do you manage your state at the component level` - what do you mean by this? a global state in a component level or a state that is inclusive on that component?

Comment: Why not just use the ordinary state management (useState) on component level?

Comment: I don't get it. If the data is only used in the component and it's children, then just put it in the component's state and not in the Redux store. That's a perfectly fine option, even if you _also_ connect that component to Redux  as well for other data.

Answer (score 2):

I think the container with `complicated state` that you want to control the same with `pure React` when redux and other tool manage state not yet appear.
In your case, the Container is a root Component (like App Component at index). It manage complicated state object and pass key value or some function to children.

```
Class Container extend Component {
   state = {
       // complicated state
   }

   render() {
       return (
          <Children1 key1={this.state.value1...} />
          <Children2 key1={this.state.value2...} />
          <Children3 key1={this.state.value3...} />
       )
   }
}
```

Or you can use Functional Component to manage state more flexible:

```
const Container = () => {
   const [state1, setState1] = useState({ // some key: value here });
   const [state2, setState2] = useState({ // some key: value here });
   const [state3, setState3] = useState({ // some key: value here });
   return (
      <Children1 keyObject={state1} keyValue={state1...} />
      <Children2 keyObject={state2} />
      <Children3 keyObject={state3} />
   )
}
```

**Answer with your Edit**: 
I think **useState** is better approach for your case. When you doing with client-side, you must control ***where variable used***. The splitting of state will help you control them more flexible.
If you have a lot of **useState** statements, you should thinking about reworked structure of Container and children Component.